# Call MVC file download action method from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, action, download

If I have the following MVC Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetDocument(int id, string fileName)
{
    // ..... // 
    return File(fileStream, "text/plain", fileName);
}
```

I want to call the action on a click of a table row using jQuery. But I'm a bit confused, because I don't think I want an Ajax call here do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do this with Ajax, as the response will be provided through the XmlHttpRequest, which is essentially useless at this point. You will need to do a standard post.

What you will likely need to do, is, if you need it to be a post, wrap up a form:

```
<form action="{mvc-route-here}" method="post"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form>
```

Or change it from a POST to a GET and use a standard hyperlink:

```
<a href="{mvc-route-here}">Submit</a>
```

...etc

Comment: your hyperlink suggestion gave me an idea and I ended up doing a redirect through jquery, something like: `$table.find('tr').click(function () { var docId = $(this).find('td.documentId).html(); window.location.href = blah + docId; });` which leaves the user on the same page but downloads the document.